# Cannot connect to the Google Cloud SQL through GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I can not connect to the **Google Cloud SQL** through GAS (Google Apps Script).

**Scenario:**

User A (other person) in Domain：A
User B (me) in Domain：A

First, User A was working with me. We have another google account in the same domain. User A created a project and created a cloud sql instance in the project and I was told by User A the instance name, database name, user and password.

I tried to execute a GAS script in order to User A to successfully connect but it returned the following error: **"Can't establish database connection."**

**GAS Src:**

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://" + instanceName + "/" + dbname, userid, userPwd);
```

I tried a couple of ways.

1. I was added by a member of the project where the database instance was created.
2. I was asked to allow my public IP.(I was able to connect with mysql workbenth this way.)

The above two methods all resulted in the same error.

Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: Ask A to add you as CloudSQL Admin role in the sql project instance in IAM.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to connect to an instance via Public IP, you need to be authenticated in some way. There are generally 3 main ways to do this: using a Service Account with the correct IAM permissions (this is what the cloud-sql-proxy does), using an SSL/TLS certificate, or whitelisting and IP.

Since you can't control the IP that GAS will connect from, you should consider the other two. I would suggest using the [JDBC SocketFactory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) - you provide it with a service account, and it provides an authenticated connection to your instance.